# The name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class.dart(invalid_constructor_name) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning flutter and in the process I am running into many challenges.

I have come across this error with a code I have inside a riverpod 2.0 Notifier class:
**The name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class.dart(invalid_constructor_name)**

Here is the function that has the error:

```
fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : cellPhone = firestore['cellPhone'],
        address1 = firestore['address1'],
        address2 = firestore['address2'],
        company = firestore['company'],
        companyId = firestore['companyId'],
        userId = firestore['userId'],
        city = firestore['city'],
        fName = firestore['fName'],
        lName = firestore['lName'],
        officePhone = firestore['officePhone'],
        state = firestore['state'],
        zipcode = firestore['zipCode'],
        mls = firestore['mls'],
        mlsId = firestore['mlsId'],
        email = firestore['email'];
```

I don't understand how to fix this error. I have searched and not found anything helpful to me.

Here is the entire Notifier class that contains the code in question:

```
class UsersNotifier extends Notifier<Users> {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  final companyRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('Company'));
  final userDB = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('users'));

// **************************************************

  @override
  Users build() {
    return Users(  // Return the initial state
      userId: '',
      fName: '',
      lName: '',
      address1: '',
      address2: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      zipCode: '',
      cellPhone: '',
      officePhone: '',
      email: '',
      companyId: '',
      companyName: '',
      mlsId: '',
      mls: '',
    );
  }  

  fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : cellPhone = firestore['cellPhone'],
        address1 = firestore['address1'],
        address2 = firestore['address2'],
        company = firestore['company'],
        companyId = firestore['companyId'],
        userId = firestore['userId'],
        city = firestore['city'],
        fName = firestore['fName'],
        lName = firestore['lName'],
        officePhone = firestore['officePhone'],
        state = firestore['state'],
        zipcode = firestore['zipCode'],
        mls = firestore['mls'],
        mlsId = firestore['mlsId'],
        email = firestore['email'];
  }
}
```

How do I fix this error in the way I am using the code?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line

```dart
fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
```

with

```dart
UsersNotifier.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
```

since it's a constructor from the enclosing class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, now all of the parameters or variables, cellPhone, address1, address2, etc., give this error: 'cellPhone' isn't a field in the enclosing class.
but I have extended Notifier<Users>. Why is this not working? Thanks again.

Comment: Take a look at [Named constructors](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#named-constructors) in Dart: that's what you're actually defining in your class when you declare `fromFirestore`. Note that, as you can see in the documentation example, you must explicitly define the fields in the current class, such as `final String cellPhone` etc. Since declaring the fields twice is not doable in your case, you may declare `fromFirestore` as a [static method](https://dart.dev/language/classes#static-methods).